# Why isolating a vector becomes transposed?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, inner-products, transformation

I am following the PCA course from Coursera and while the instructor was isolating the beta coefficient from the following equation; $ x_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \beta_{in}b_{i} $, he ended with $\beta_{in} = x_{n}^Tb_{i}$. My question is, why does the $x_{n}$ becomes $x_{n}^T$ and not $x_{n}^{-1}$? And what happened to $\sum_{i=1}^{D}$?

I'm available to go ahead with the course without knowing what's going on but I really want to understand everything, so I will appreciate your answers so much.

Comment: You can't take inverses of vectors. Remember that for vectors $x,y$, the $1\times 1$ matrix $x^\top y$ is considered just a scalar and that is the dot product of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

We're missing a lot of context, but here's my best guess at what's going on.

The vectors $b_1,\dots,b_n$ are an orthonormal (perhaps principal components), which is to say that $b_i^Tb_j$ is $1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise. It follows that for any $i$, we have
$$
x_n^Tb_i = b_i^T x_n = b_i^T \sum_{j=1}^D \beta_{in}b_j = \sum_{j=1}^D \beta_{in} \cdot (b_i^Tb_j)  = \beta_{in}.
$$

---

The following perspective might be helpful. In terms of matrices, the first equation can be written as
$$
x_n = B \beta_n,
$$
where $B$ is the matrix with columns $b_1,\dots,b_n$ and $\beta_n$ is the column-vector with entries $\beta_{1n}, \dots \beta_{Dn}$. By obtaining an equation of the form $\beta_{in} = \cdots$, we are solving for the vector $\beta_n$ in the above equation.

Typically, in order to solve the above equation, we would have to "divide both sides by $B$", in a sense. As long as the columns of $B$ are linearly independent, we could proceed as follows: there exists a "left inverse" $C$ of the matrix $B$ for which $CB = I_{D \times D}$, and we could multiply both sides by $C$ to find that
$$
Cx_n = CB \beta_n = I\beta_n = \beta_n,
$$
which is to say that we have solved for $\beta_n$. Generally speaking, there is no "nice" formula for the entries of $C$; one common generic approach is to make $C$ the [MP pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) of $B$.

In our particular case, we know that the columns of $B$ are orthonormal, which makes it very easy to divide by $B$: we can simply take $C = B^T$. With that, the equation becomes
$$
B^TB \beta_n = \beta_n = B^T x_n.
$$
Now, each entry of $\beta_n$ is one of the values of $\beta_{in}$, and each entry of $B^Tx_n$ is a dot-product between a column of $B$ and the vector $x_n$. Putting that all together, we see that we have $\beta_{in} = b_i^Tx_n$ for each $i$.

Comment: So that guy was not only passing the $\beta$ to the other side, uh?. He was representing $\beta_{in}$ as the dot product indeed lol.

Comment: Later had $J = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left| x_{n} - \widetilde{x_{n}} \right \|^2$ and he said it's partial derivative is $\frac{\partial{J}}{\partial {\widetilde{x_{n}}}} = -\frac{2}{N}(x_{n} - \widetilde{x_{n}})^T$ where does the transpose came from? @Ben Grossmann

Comment: @RosendoOcaña You might find my edit to be helpful. The short answer to your comment is that you need to carefully look at the definition of the derivative that the instructor uses: try to use the definition to see why it is that for a function $J:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, the derivative must be a row vector.

Comment: @RosendoOcaña If you're having trouble using this hint, I suggest that you ask a new question. It would be helpful if, in this new question, you included the definition of a derivative that your instructor gives.